# MySQL query to return the rows of the least matched conditions

Tags: mysql, count

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT a.*  FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b on (a.id = b.id)
WHERE a.somefield = 300 AND a.anotherfield IN ('Option-A','Option-B')
ORDER BY a.field_order ASC
```

Now the tricky part is the second condition `AND a.anotherfield IN ('Option-A','Option-B')`, based on it's value, I get a total rows of:

```
+------------------------------------+
+  Condition Value   | Returned Rows +
+------------------------------------+
+ Option-A           |      10       +
+ Option-B           |       3       +
+ Option-A, Option-B |      13       +
+------------------------------------+
```

I need to only return the **LEAST** returned rows of the conditions. I still need to include Option-A and Option-B in the condition side of the query, but I want the rows of the lesser matched condition only, i.e. 3 rows based on the above example, not 13 which is the combination of both conditions.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? And what do you want to do if two options have the same number of rows?

Comment: I can use any version of MySQL if that makes it easier. I am looking to return the first "least" set of rows so if two conditions have the same amount of rows, return the rows of the first condition only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COUNT() window function in your query to count the rows in each group and finally filter the rows with a CASE expression:

```
SELECT * -- you may want to enumerate only the columns of TableA
FROM (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN a.anotherfield = 'Option-A' THEN 1 END) OVER () opta,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN a.anotherfield = 'Option-B' THEN 1 END) OVER () optb 
  FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b on (a.id = b.id)
  WHERE a.somefield = 300 AND a.anotherfield IN ('Option-A','Option-B')
) t
WHERE anotherfield = CASE LEAST(opta, optb)
  WHEN opta THEN 'Option-A'
  WHEN optb THEN 'Option-B'
END
```

Comment: @forpas That's a great way of doing it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note MySQL accepts the less verbose method too!